# How to print different results to a screen and to a file in python?

Tags: python, bash, httpie

I have noticed that the `httpie` python tool gives different results in the following two caes:

1. `$ http google.com`
2. `$ http google.com > out.txt`

The file `out.txt` misses headers that are present in the first case.

Comment: I am a little confused as to what the error is exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the manual page of `http` you can find the following

```
Output options:
 --print WHAT, -p WHAT

   String specifying what the output should contain:

   'H' request headers 'B' request body 'h' response headers 'b' response body

   The default behaviour is 'hb' (i.e., the response headers  and  body  is 
   printed), if standard  output  is  not redirected. If the output is piped
   to another program or to a file, then only the response body is printed by
   default.
```

Which indicates that `http` intentionally behaves differently whenever the output is redirected. To obtain the same behavior as for not redirected output you can use

```
`http --print hb google.com > out.txt`
```

(But also note that pretty-printing behaves differently with redirection.)

Comment: Oops, seeing that this answer was accepted, I guess my answer was totally off. I thought the question is about "how to print different results to a screen and to a file" when *writing* a Python program. :-]

Answer (score 2):

Use `sys.stdout.isatty` to tell whether `stdout` is a terminal (a "tty") or a file and print different output depending on that, e.g.:

```
import sys
if sys.stdout.isatty():
    print "Hello terminal!"
else:
    print "Hello non-terminal!"
```